# Distinct point of intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Consider the family of curves $$y=\frac{1}{n}x^2+n$$ where $n=1,2,\ldots,100$. Prove that there does not exist three curves that intersect at the same point.

I'm trying to experiment with point of intersection within a family of curves. I know how to prove that if $n$ only takes on prime values then the result is true. I'm not sure how to prove this for a generic list of values for $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose three curves intersect at the same point $(a,b)$ for distinct $n_1,n_2,n_3$. Then

$b\ =\ \dfrac1{n_1}a^2+n_1\ =\ \dfrac1{n_2}a^2+n_2$

$\implies\ a^2\ =\ n_1n_2$

Similarly we have

$b\ =\ \dfrac1{n_1}a^2+n_1\ =\ \dfrac1{n_3}a^2+n_3$

$\implies\ a^2=n_1n_3$

Hence $n_1n_2=n_1n_3$ and since $n_1\ne0$, $n_2=n_3$ contradicting the fact that they are distinct.

So there can't be three distinct curves with a common intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Note that, for $0\lt n_1\lt n_2$, we have

$$\frac{1}{n_1}x^2+n_1=\frac{1}{n_2}x^2+n_2\iff \frac{n_2-n_1}{n_1n_2}x^2=n_2-n_1\iff x^2=n_1n_2$$

So, supposing that
$$\frac{1}{n_1}x^2+n_1=\frac{1}{n_2}x^2+n_2=\frac{1}{n_3}x^2+n_3$$
for $0\lt n_1\lt n_2\lt n_3$ gives
$$(x^2=)\ n_1n_2=n_2n_3$$
which is impossible.